# how to get object field from database

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, web

I have entity:

```
public class Answer {
private Long id;
private Question question;
private String answer;
private boolean isRight;
}
```

How can I get the "isRight" field from the database?

in the DaoImpl i tried this:

```
public Boolean isAnswerRight(Long questionId, Long answerId) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select a from Answer where a.question.id = :questionId AND a.id = :answerId", Answer.class)
            .setParameter("questionId", questionId)
            .setParameter("answerId", answerId)
            .getSingleResult()
            .isRight();
}
```

but teamlead said: "you get the whole object from the database, get the field right away"

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like below.

Alternatively, you could only `SELECT isRight` column from DB.

Also, if you have answerId - this should suffice to identify answer uniquely, so no need for additional parameter for question ID.

```
public Boolean isAnswerRight(Long answerId) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select * from Answer a where a.id = :answerId", Answer.class)
        .setParameter("answerId", answerId)
        .getSingleResult()
        // assuming you have getter getIsRight for isRight field
        .getIsRight();
}
```

or

```
public Answer getAnswerById(Long answerId) {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select * from Answer a where a.id = :answerId", Answer.class)
        .setParameter("answerId", answerId)
        .getSingleResult();
}

Answer answer = getAnswerById(answerId);
// assuming you have getter for isRight field
Boolean isAnswerRight = answer.getIsRight();
```